# Great flask / other python micro framework code I could learn from

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I'd like to look at some good web-app code written in python, just so I can learn some of the patterns / see how I can improve my code.

I've already googled around a bit, used google code search and run a search on github too - but haven't come across a well built, comprehensive app.

Perhaps a book could work as well. Basically, I'm just trying to find a way to learn the basic programming patterns for web-applications.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure of the best body of python code. But I always use and recommend Python itself as the first place to look if you want to know the best way to code up a specific problem in C.

Comment: Web app code, or web app *framework* code?  And if the former, a web app built with Flask only, or with any framework?

Comment: @sean the former (since the framework code is easily available) - Flask would be ideal, but failing that other lucid code i can learn patterns from..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good lightweight Python MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986/whats-a-good-lightweight-python-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not start with the publicly available [flask.pocoo.org](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/website)?

Note: I'm linking to the Github repository on which he has published the code for his website (which runs on flask) rather than the website itself.

Comment: @flyingcrab Go ahead with what Sean has suggested. I asked a similar question when I was picking a framework to start with web app development . Am very glad that I went with Sean's advise and went with Flask. Have learnt a lot since that day!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your time would be better invested learning something like Django, because much of what you could improve in a micro framework is already builtin on a bigger framework.

Comment: hey, thats a fair point - but i guess what i am trying to do is build some of this functionality so i learn how it works. which requires me reading some code first ... hence the motivation for this question.

Comment: I see. Still they are both MVC, so many patterns and techniques apply to both frameworks - and you can benefit from Django bigger ecosystem.